# Create systemd unit in cloud-init and enable it

Tags: ubuntu-16.04, systemd, cloud-init

I've created the following systemd unit in the cloud-init file:

```
- path: /etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/docker-compose.service
  owner: root:root
  permissions: '0755'
  content: |
      [Unit]
      Description=Docker Compose Boot Up
      Requires=docker.service
      After=docker.service

      [Service]
      Type=simple
      ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/docker-compose -f /opt/data/docker-compose.yml up -d
      Restart=always
      RestartSec=30

      [Install]
      WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

When I try to run

`sudo systemctl enable docker-compose.service`

to create the symlink I get this:

`Failed to execute operation: No such file or directory`

However I'm sure that the file is under `/etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check that every file involved is present and valid:

```
 ls -l  /etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/docker-compose.service
 ls -l /usr/local/bin/docker-compose
 ls -l /opt/data/docker-compose.yml
 systemd-analyze verify /etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/docker-compose.service
```

Also consider the timing. Even if the files exist once they are fully booted, would `/etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/` exist when `cloud-init` runs?

Answer (score 2):

I had the same need, but I was working from a recipe that said to create `/etc/systemd/system/unit.service` and then do `systemctl enable --now unit`.

So I created the unit file with `write_files` and did the reload and enable in a `text/x-shellscript` part and that worked fine. (User scripts run last and in order, while I don't think there are guarantees about when the `write_files` key in the user-data is processed. I found out the hard way that it's before the `user` key so you can't set ownership to users that cloud-init creates).

I think `runcmd` entries are converted to user scripts and run in list order (either before or after the other user scripts), so if you don't like `x-shellscript` parts you can do the reload and enable that way. `/var/log/cloud-init.log` is where I check the order, there is probably a config file too.

Full disclosure: I forgot the `systemctl daemon-reload` command but it still worked. Actually there is a caveat against systemd manipulations from cloud-init because it's running under systemd itself and some systemd commands may wait for cloud-init to finish -- deadlock!

Answer (score 1):

After unit file creation but before any manipulations with it systemd should be notified about the changes:

```
systemctl daemon-reload
```

So cloud-init YAML block creating `docker-compose.service` file should be followed by:

```
runcmd:
- systemctl daemon-reload
```